# Почему в Windows нет отображения размера папок в режиме Таблица в проводнике,как у одиновных файлов например?

Tags: windows, explorer

Почему в Windows нет отображения размера папок в режиме Таблица в проводнике,как у одиновных файлов например?
Требуется видеть сразу объемы папок а не по каждой кликать и смотреть свойства...
Выручает сторонний софт.

Answer (score 1):

Сделать подсчёт объема каждой папки - не беда. А если в ней вложенность в несколько тысяч папок, в которых несколько тысяч других папок, в которых тысячи файлов? Будет уходить слишком много ресурсов на подсчёт, слишком много времени. Поэтому MS решила убрать этот функционал. А сторонние утилиты - это хорошо. Но до поры, до времени.